# Detections from CaffeModel are outside of image bounds

Tags: c#, opencv, caffe

I'm trying to make a program that will detect and anonymize faces on things like ID cards. I translated [a python example I found](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/) to C# and it worked flawlessly on most examples. However, some images yield detections that are out of bounds.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a new console project.
2. Add the nuget package: '[OpenCvSharp4.Windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4.Windows/4.1.0.20190416)'.
3. Download the required files (bottom of this question).
4. Insert the code and put the files in a folder you name files in the debug folder of the program.

**Code to reproduce:**

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    anonymize( new byte[][] { File.ReadAllBytes("files\\elon-musk.jpg") }, "files\\deploy.prototxt", "files\\model.caffemodel" );
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void anonymize( byte[][] files, string caffeProtoTxtFile, string caffeModelFile )
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach( var fileBytes in files )
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine( $"Image nr.{i}" );
        using( var net = OpenCvSharp.Dnn.Net.ReadNetFromCaffe( caffeProtoTxtFile, caffeModelFile ) )
        {
            var image = Cv2.ImDecode( fileBytes, ImreadModes.AnyColor | ImreadModes.AnyDepth );

            Console.WriteLine( $"\nImage size:\nWidth:{image.Width}\nHeight:{image.Height}\n\n" );

            var detections = detectFaceDNN( image, net, true );
            image.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

private static Rect[] detectFaceDNN( Mat image, OpenCvSharp.Dnn.Net net, bool draw )
{
    var detectionRectangles = new List<Rect>();

    using( var blob = OpenCvSharp.Dnn.CvDnn.BlobFromImage( image, 1, size: new Size( image.Width, image.Height ), mean: new Scalar( 91.4953, 103.8827, 131.0912 ) ) )
    {
        net.SetInput( blob );
        using( var detections = net.Forward() )
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < detections.Size( 2 ); i++ )
            {
                var confidence = detections.At<float>( 0, 0, i, 2 );

                if( confidence > 0.85 )
                {
                    var startX = (int)Math.Round( detections.At<float>( 0, 0, i, 3 ) * image.Width );
                    var startY = (int)Math.Round( detections.At<float>( 0, 0, i, 4 ) * image.Height );
                    var endX = (int)Math.Round( detections.At<float>( 0, 0, i, 5 ) * image.Width );
                    var endY = (int)Math.Round( detections.At<float>( 0, 0, i, 6 ) * image.Height );

                    var coordinatesOutOfBounds = endX > image.Width || endY > image.Height || startX < 0 || startY < 0;

                    //Don't draw if its out of bounds
                    if( coordinatesOutOfBounds )
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine( $"Coordinates:\nX: {startX} - {endX}\nY: {startY.ToString().PadLeft(4)} - {endY.ToString().PadLeft(4)}\n" );
                        continue;
                    }

                    if( draw )
                        Cv2.Rectangle( image, pt1: new Point( startX, startY ), pt2: new Point( endX, endY ), color: new Scalar(), thickness: -1 );

                    detectionRectangles.Add( new Rect( startX, startY, endX - startX, endY - startY ) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return detectionRectangles.ToArray();
}
```

This code will output any coordinates that are out of bounds.

**Files:**
[CaffeModel](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15GgnPPyOy-IQy_EuAeIL-J1slnBf_G1Y)
[Prototxt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FhyVfgVpDhL3bZ-HVrLj0gx_8tdEU2f7)
[Image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LpnCcy0VlhAkH4gR1O1ejD47hXoPimHn)

As I can't use images used in production (privacy sensitive information) I found another image that also has these coordinates.

Essentially my question is why am I getting these 'invalid' coordinates from the detections but the other valid coordinates are in the correct place and everything. I feel like I'm doing something wrong and should not get these detections otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is happening sometime, but not always (in my case), you should do the following checking before going for the other stuff:

```
if (startX < 0) {
    startX = 0;
}
if (startY < 0) {
    startY  = 0;
}
if (startX + (endX - startX ) > frame.cols) {
    endX = frame.cols;
}
if (startY + (endY - startY ) > frame.rows) {
    endY = frame.rows;
}
```

So it will be inbound now.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I already do this check practically (you can see it in the question) Problem is if both Y coordinates are outside bounds and I set them to the number of rows the detection will have a height of 0 (so I'd be better off just not doing those coordinates and skipping as I do now). For instance startY can be 1000 even tho the image is 800 rows

Comment: You just did check but did not assign the new value to the x and y

Comment: That won't work. If you use my code you will see many detections have startY and endY both out of bounds, if i'd make both equal to the number of rows it would have a height of 0. And if I were to use your code endY would be lower then startY. Please use my example and you will see that it does not work like that.

Comment: Also the point of the detections won't really work if I change to coordinates as they will be in the incorrect place

Comment: Because I was also facing the same problem, and I just add the code above, and then now it is working well.

Comment: I am not using C#, so I cannot run your code, C++, JAVA, Python I am using.

Comment: My point is a detection with the height of 0 is useless. Read my comment again and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: I just shared my experience with you, if it did not solve your problem, leave it and go for the next solution.